# Can't catch my exception

Tags: c++, exception, boost-test

I've created the following exception class(es):

```
namespace json {

    /**
     * @brief Base class for all json-related exceptions
     */
    class Exception : public std::exception { };

    /**
     * @brief Indicates an internal exception of the json parser
     */
    class InternalException : public Exception {

    public:
        /**
         * @brief Constructs a new InternalException
         *
         * @param msg The message to return on what()
         */
        InternalException( const std::string& msg );
        ~InternalException() throw ();

        /**
         * @brief Returns a more detailed error message
         *
         * @return The error message
         */
        virtual const char* what() const throw();

    private:
        std::string _msg;

    };
}
```

Implementations(s):

```
InternalException::InternalException( const std::string& msg ) : _msg( msg ) { }
InternalException::~InternalException() throw () { };

const char* InternalException::what() const throw() {
    return this->_msg.c_str();
}
```

I throw the exception like this:

```
throw json::InternalException( "Cannot serialize uninitialized nodes." );
```

I wanted to test the exception-throwing behaviour in a Boost::Test unit test:

```
// [...]
BOOST_CHECK_THROW( json::write( obj ), json::InternalException );  //will cause a json::InternalException
```

However, the test exits when the exception occurs as if there was no try...catch.

If I make the try...catch explicit and surround the `json::write()` call with `try{ json.write(obj); }catch(const json::InternalException& ex){}` or even `try{json.write(obj);}catch(...){}`, I get the same behaviour. The exception is raised, but I can't catch it no matter what.

The output I get is the following:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'json::InternalException'
what():  Cannot serialize uninitialized nodes.
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Could be any reason. Usually a missing compile.

Comment: Are you sure the exception is raised ? Other notes on your code, avoid the throw declarator (or use noexcept if your compiler supports it) and derive from std::runtime_error so you don't have to write the logic of the `what` string

Comment: You have not included the code for `write`, but my bet is that you simply throw another exception

Comment: @Geoffroy When targetting a mix of compilers which do and don't support `noexcept`, using `throw()` is the only way to write such functions.

Comment: Can you provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)? Maybe more than one exception occurs.

Comment: I definitely throw the correct exception, I just changed the exception message in json::write() to something unique, and the program now quits with that message.

Comment: @DeX3: Is it possible that a second exception is thrown by a destructor while the stack is unwinding? That's the most likely reason for termination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it. I figured it out while trying to throw an SSCCE together for you guys. I had `json::write()` declared with a throw specifier, but didn't include `json::InternalException`.

Adjusting the throw specifier to the correct exception now lets me actually catch it. Thanks for all the hints.

Comment: I'd remove the specifier altogether. Dynamic exception specifiers are mostly useless, to the extent that they're now deprecated.

Comment: Thank's, I'll remove them